# Replace "special" Strings /---? in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace

I already know how to replace simple characters or strings in powershell but now I have a headache with a "special" string.

For a **normal** string/text this line works perfectly fine.

```
(Get-Content $file.PSPath).Replace('lucky', 'dog') |
    Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

If I want to replace a string which contains a string/text like `/---?` it doesn't work.

```
(Get-Content $file.PSPath).Replace('de/---?lucky', 'dog') |
    Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

Also there is no error.

Comment: `.Replace()` does an exact match. Just wondering have you checked if your pattern is exact or not.

Comment: That ought to work. Could it be an encoding problem?

Comment: If you'd have used ` -replace('de/---?lucky', 'dog')` you'd have to escape the `?` with a backslash `\?` due to RegEx, otherwise I agree with @VivekKumarSingh.

Comment: So I when I use -replace it should look like this:  -replace('de/---\?lucky', 'dog')`

Comment: thanks, I made a few tests and i think I found a solution -->  -replace 'de/\?___lucky',dog'  worked for me!